# Transparency in overlayed png makes background transparent too

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two movie clips, one is a background and the other contains user generated drawing.  This includes erasing which I do with:

```
eraserDraw.graphics.lineStyle(shapeSize.width, 0x000000);
```

This all displays fine in a browser.  You can erase lines to see the background but when I come to save it as a png the background cannot be seen.  The transparency seems to go all the way to the bottom instead of showing the background.

Here is what I have:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imgWidth, imgHeight, true, 0x00000000);
bmd.draw(background);
bmd.draw(foreground);
var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);
```

Thanks

Solved:

I needed:

```
background.cacheAsBitmap = true;
foreground.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

Comment: um bmd.draw is probably just overwriting the pixels when you do the second write.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set [cacheAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap) to `true` for both your Bitmaps.